# C++11 resources and compilers

Tags: c++, c++11

What is the recommended resource(s) for learning the new features in C++11? Is there any book on it yet? Does latest versions of g++/Visual Studio support it?

Comment: A quick search would easily answer all of those questions, and of course, the standard itself is open.

Comment: google is not intelligent yet to give accurate recommendations.

Comment: @Ed: The standard may be open, but it's not free.

Comment: @fazo: A Google search doesn't come up with any programmer-friendly, in-depth overview of C++11. That's why cod3r asked here. Did you try it yourself before posting your silly comment?

Comment: @TonyK yes, i ended in wikipedia and then in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11 which is pretty basic google result

Comment: @fazo: Then surely you see the problem? If that Wikipedia page is all there is, then we programmers are screwed. The new ISO standard is for compiler writers, not C++ programmers. Thankfully, that Wikipedia page is +not+ all there is -- there are many good articles on different aspects of C++11. But there is no single programmer-friendly source for all the many new features.

Comment: @TonyK: No?  Did you look at my link?  Bjarne maintains a comprehensive FAQ, what is lacking there?

Comment: @Ed: Bjarne Stroustrup's FAQ is a useful resource. But it devotes less than 50 lines of text to rvalue references. The OP is looking for an exposition, not a FAQ.

Comment: @EdS. I'm pretty sure nobody learns the new features be reading through the standard document, nice suggestion ;)

Comment: @Christian: You'd be wrong then I guess.  When I want to know how something works at a low level, I go for the standard.

Comment: @EdS. I agree that as a high-detail-low-level reference it surely has value, but as an overview and introduction to the new features it is completely useless.

Comment: @ChristianRau : I happen to agree with Ed :-/

Comment: There are 3 worthwhile books for c++11 http://www.artima.com/shop/cpp_and_beyond_2010 http://www.artima.com/shop/overview_of_the_new_cpp and relatively less helpful http://www.amazon.com/Professional-C-Marc-Gregoire/dp/0470932449/ref=sr_1_31?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1318454003&sr=1-31  . Good Luck!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The current versions of g++ and VC++ each support *some* features of C++11, but neither supports everything (overall, I'd say g++ currently supports *more* of the new features though). MS has revealed what they plan to add to the next version of VC++; the short summary is "not a lot". Both do, however, have some fairly important new features covered pretty well (e.g., both seem to handle lambdas pretty well).

As far as resources like books go, they're currently pretty meager. *C++ Concurrency in action* (by Anthony Williams) covers the new threading library, but that's nearly the only one (and it's obviously covers only one new aspect).

Answer (score 8):

C++11 was only just standardized, so any compiler support is experimental because it wasn't a standard when support was introduced. Apache has a wiki article that lists which compilers support which C++11 features.

Source: http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport

gcc is the best bet at this point. gcc 4.5 supports a majority of features and is in pretty much every recent Linux distribution now. Obviously newer versions are better. Their support page explains which versions support which features.

Source: http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

Visual Studio 10 has decent support. This MSDN blog article lists which features are supported in 10 and are planned for 11.

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx

The Intel C++ compiler seems to be the only other compiler with decent support. I don't know much about it though and I don't think it's free. According to this article version 12 seems to be decent, but I'm not sure if that's released or in development.

Source: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/c0x-features-supported-by-intel-c-compiler/

Answer (score 4):

The Wikipedia page about C++11 has a nice list of features, but it might not be exhaustive. The status of C++11 support in GCC [can be found here](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html), in Clang it [can be found here](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html).